# Using Cell Properties defined in the Measure to format icCube Table

Tags: iccube-reporting

I have one Measure with BACK_COLOR and FORE_COLOR defined and another without this definition. I would like to show these measures in an icCube Table as they are defined. In icCube5 there was a flag 'Allow HTML' that did exactly that.
Now in icCube6.8.11 and 7.0.0 I don't find it anymore.

Here is the definition of the first measure (traffic quality):

```
format_string = '##0.00 %', BACK_COLOR = traffic_quality_color(currentCellValue()), FORE_COLOR=RGB("#666666")
```

In the beginning the BACK_COLOR in the table is always white and the FORE_COLOR is always black.
If I change the Cell Background Color in the chart to MDX->Cell Property->BACK_COLOR then both columns have the BACK_COLOR defined in the first Measure, but the FORE_COLOR seems to be used.

[image]

What do I have to do, in order to have the second measure in black and white and the first measure colorful?

Comment: it's fixed in RC2

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking forward to RC2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked out the new version and the coloring is correct in the icCube table without any further configuration. Thank you very much!